# How to change Required in an input tag to false

Tags: vb.net, html, vbscript

I have this HTML code and want to press the back button without the input data to be required so it can be redirected back to the previous page, needs to be in vb.net.

```
<form runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="first" runat="server" Required/></td>
        <td>Surname:</td><td><input type="text" id="last" runat="server" Required/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td><input type="date" id="birth" runat="server" Required/></td>
        <td>Gender:</td><td><select id="gender" runat="server" Required><option>Male</option><option>Female</option></select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Known Illnesses:</td><td><input type="text" id="illnesses" runat="server" Required/></td>
        <td>Nationality:</td><td><input type="text" id="country" runat="server" Required/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="email" id="mail" runat="server" Required/></td>
        <td>Mobile:</td><td><input type="number" id="phone" runat="server" Required/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employer:</td><td><input type="text" id="company" runat="server" Required/></td>
        <td>Emergency Contact Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="emergencyperson" runat="server" Required/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Emergency Contact Number:</td><td><input type="number" id="emergencyphone" runat="server" Required/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="btnUpdate" value="Update" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="btnBack" value="Back" runat="server" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <p id="parMsg" runat="server"></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must delete the `required` attribute. If it is present, the `<input>` is requiring data.